# link to page with $_SERVER REQUEST_METHOD 'GET' does not load

Tags: php, internal-server-error, get-request

I have a verification link like this:
`http://nailsalon.gwiddle.co.uk/nailsalon/verify.php?email=email@enail.com&hash=66808e327dc79d135ba18e051673d906`.

When I click it or manually insert it to the address bar I get `error 500` or `File not found`. The page which I am trying to access through this link uses the `$_GET` array.

When I use a link like this:
`http://nailsalon.gwiddle.co.uk/nailsalon/index.php?id=1` which leads to a page which doesn't use the `$_GET` it loads without problem.

There is another question with the same problem but no solution here:
[Internal server error on email verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698446/internal-server-error-on-email-verification)

Here is the code of the target page:

```
if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){
    $email = clear_entry($_GET['email']);
    $hash = clear_entry($_GET['hash']);

    /*Query that retrieves all users with the given email and hash*/
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' AND hash='$hash' AND is_activated='0'");

    /*Checks if the account is already verified*/
    if ($result->num_rows == 0 ){

        $_SESSION['message'] = "Account has already been activated or the URL is invalid!";
        header("location: error.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Your account has been successfully activated!";
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET is_activated='1' WHERE user_email='$email'") or die($mysqli->error);
        $_SESSION['active'] = 1;
        header("location: success.php");
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Invalid parameters provided for account verification!";
    echo "Invalid parameters provided for account verification!";
    header("location: error.php");

}
?>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that my website is uploaded on gwiddle.co.uk.

Comment: Please Show verify.php file code.

Comment: 500 means "Internal Server Error". I'm pretty shure there is an error in your PHP-Code. Please show us the relevant PHP-Code.